# Reading JSON and String in same Spring Kafka application

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Well, I have an application that reads 2 topics from Kafka, the first is just a plain String, and the second topic is a JSON that should be converted to DTO.

If I use the RecordMessageConverter:

```
 @Bean
 public RecordMessageConverter converter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }
```

The first topic (just string) raise an exception to convert String to DTO, because StringJsonMessageConverter try to do it. But the second topic works normally.

Any tips , how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom [deserializer](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html) of Object and use [this](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#KafkaConsumer-java.util.Properties-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer-org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer-) constructor. For key deserializer, your case perhaps [StringDeserializer](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringDeserializer.html) would suffice. In the deserializer, you could override the [deserialize](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.html#deserialize-java.lang.String-byte:A-) method and from the topic name determine the type of deserialization to perform. During processing, i.e. after call to poll determine the type of Object and process accordingly.

Other way, of course is to use two consumers individually.

Comment: But to use two consumers individually I will need two applications, right?

Comment: Not 2 applications, 2 consumer instances only.

Comment: Ok, I will see it. Thanks